# How to arrange the data in PowerBi using Dax?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have the data in following format where column 1 is username and column 2 is platforms. I want to create a venn diagram in Power Bi. For that I need to

**Format in which I have the data**:

| User Name | Platforms |
| --- | --- |
| User 1 | Instagram |
| User 3 | Facebook |
| User 1 | Instagram |
| User 3 | Facebook |
| User 2 | YouTube |
| User 4 | Facebook |
| User 1 | YouTube |
| User 3 | YouTube |
| User 1 | YouTube |
| User 3 | YouTube |
| User 1 | Instagram |
| User 3 | Facebook |
| User 1 | Twitter |
| User 3 | Twitter |
| User 1 | Twitter |
| User 3 | Twitter |
| User 1 | Instagram |
| User 3 | Facebook |

**Format in which I want to arrange the data**:

[Required Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbMRC.jpg)

Any help would be appretiated.

I can do this in excel but the problem is that this is a part of larger dataset and hence need to do this programatically through DAX.

Comment: Can it be in Powerquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following as a Calculated Table:
This one is more unique users:

```
SocialVennDiagram = 
  var gp1Users = CALCULATETABLE(DISTINCT('UserSocial'[User Name]), 'UserSocial'[Platforms] = "Instagram")
  var gp2Users = CALCULATETABLE(DISTINCT('UserSocial'[User Name]), 'UserSocial'[Platforms] = "Twitter")
  var gp3Users = CALCULATETABLE(DISTINCT('UserSocial'[User Name]), 'UserSocial'[Platforms] = "Facebook")
  var gp4Users = CALCULATETABLE(DISTINCT('UserSocial'[User Name]), 'UserSocial'[Platforms] = "YouTube")

  RETURN SELECTCOLUMNS(
    {
      ( 1, 0, 0, 0, COALESCE(COUNTROWS( EXCEPT(gp1Users, UNION(gp2Users, gp3Users, gp4Users)) ), 0) ),
      ( 1, 1, 0, 0, COALESCE(COUNTROWS( EXCEPT(INTERSECT(gp1Users, gp2Users), UNION(gp3Users, gp4Users)) ), 0) ),
      ( 1, 1, 1, 0, COALESCE(COUNTROWS( EXCEPT(INTERSECT(INTERSECT(gp1Users, gp2Users), gp3Users), gp4Users) ), 0) ),
      ( 1, 1, 1, 1, COALESCE(COUNTROWS( INTERSECT(INTERSECT(INTERSECT(gp1Users, gp2Users), gp3Users), gp4Users) ), 0) ),
      ( 0, 1, 0, 0, COALESCE(COUNTROWS( EXCEPT(gp2Users, UNION(gp3Users, gp4Users, gp1Users)) ), 0) ),
      ( 0, 1, 1, 0, COALESCE(COUNTROWS( EXCEPT(INTERSECT(gp2Users, gp3Users), UNION(gp4Users, gp1Users)) ), 0) ),
      ( 0, 1, 1, 1, COALESCE(COUNTROWS( EXCEPT(INTERSECT(INTERSECT(gp2Users, gp3Users), gp4Users), gp1Users) ), 0) ),
      ( 0, 0, 1, 0, COALESCE(COUNTROWS( EXCEPT(gp3Users, UNION(gp4Users, gp1Users, gp2Users)) ), 0) ),
      ( 0, 0, 1, 1, COALESCE(COUNTROWS( EXCEPT(INTERSECT(gp3Users, gp4Users), UNION(gp1Users, gp2Users)) ), 0) ),
      ( 0, 0, 0, 1, COALESCE(COUNTROWS( EXCEPT(gp4Users, UNION(gp1Users, gp2Users, gp3Users)) ), 0) ),
      ( 1, 0, 1, 0, COALESCE(COUNTROWS( EXCEPT(INTERSECT(gp1Users, gp3Users), UNION(gp2Users, gp4Users)) ), 0) ),
      ( 1, 0, 1, 1, COALESCE(COUNTROWS( EXCEPT(INTERSECT(INTERSECT(gp1Users, gp3Users), gp4Users), gp2Users) ), 0) ),
      ( 1, 0, 0, 1, COALESCE(COUNTROWS( EXCEPT(INTERSECT(gp1Users, gp4Users), UNION(gp2Users, gp3Users)) ), 0) ),
      ( 1, 0, 1, 0, COALESCE(COUNTROWS( EXCEPT(INTERSECT(gp1Users, gp3Users), UNION(gp2Users, gp4Users)) ), 0) ),
      ( 1, 1, 0, 1, COALESCE(COUNTROWS( EXCEPT(INTERSECT(INTERSECT(gp1Users, gp2Users), gp4Users), gp3Users) ), 0) )
    },
    "Number of users", [Value5],
    "Instagram", [Value1],
    "Twitter", [Value2],
    "Facebook", [Value3],
    "YouTube", [Value4]
  )
```

---

And this one is more user instances (aka visits):

```
SocialVennDiagramv2 = 
  var gp1Users = CALCULATETABLE(DISTINCT('UserSocial'[User Name]), 'UserSocial'[Platforms] = "Instagram")
  var gp2Users = CALCULATETABLE(DISTINCT('UserSocial'[User Name]), 'UserSocial'[Platforms] = "Twitter")
  var gp3Users = CALCULATETABLE(DISTINCT('UserSocial'[User Name]), 'UserSocial'[Platforms] = "Facebook")
  var gp4Users = CALCULATETABLE(DISTINCT('UserSocial'[User Name]), 'UserSocial'[Platforms] = "YouTube")
  var x = 23

  RETURN SELECTCOLUMNS(
    {
      ( 1, 0, 0, 0, COALESCE(CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('UserSocial'), 'UserSocial'[User Name] IN EXCEPT(gp1Users, UNION(gp2Users, gp3Users, gp4Users)) ), 0) ),
      ( 1, 1, 0, 0, COALESCE(CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('UserSocial'), 'UserSocial'[User Name] IN EXCEPT(INTERSECT(gp1Users, gp2Users), UNION(gp3Users, gp4Users)) ), 0) ),
      ( 1, 1, 1, 0, COALESCE(CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('UserSocial'), 'UserSocial'[User Name] IN EXCEPT(INTERSECT(INTERSECT(gp1Users, gp2Users), gp3Users), gp4Users) ), 0) ),
      ( 1, 1, 1, 1, COALESCE(CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('UserSocial'), 'UserSocial'[User Name] IN INTERSECT(INTERSECT(INTERSECT(gp1Users, gp2Users), gp3Users), gp4Users) ), 0) ),
      ( 0, 1, 0, 0, COALESCE(CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('UserSocial'), 'UserSocial'[User Name] IN EXCEPT(gp2Users, UNION(gp3Users, gp4Users, gp1Users)) ), 0) ),
      ( 0, 1, 1, 0, COALESCE(CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('UserSocial'), 'UserSocial'[User Name] IN EXCEPT(INTERSECT(gp2Users, gp3Users), UNION(gp4Users, gp1Users)) ), 0) ),
      ( 0, 1, 1, 1, COALESCE(CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('UserSocial'), 'UserSocial'[User Name] IN EXCEPT(INTERSECT(INTERSECT(gp2Users, gp3Users), gp4Users), gp1Users) ), 0) ),
      ( 0, 0, 1, 0, COALESCE(CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('UserSocial'), 'UserSocial'[User Name] IN EXCEPT(gp3Users, UNION(gp4Users, gp1Users, gp2Users)) ), 0) ),
      ( 0, 0, 1, 1, COALESCE(CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('UserSocial'), 'UserSocial'[User Name] IN EXCEPT(INTERSECT(gp3Users, gp4Users), UNION(gp1Users, gp2Users)) ), 0) ),
      ( 0, 0, 0, 1, COALESCE(CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('UserSocial'), 'UserSocial'[User Name] IN EXCEPT(gp4Users, UNION(gp1Users, gp2Users, gp3Users)) ), 0) ),
      ( 1, 0, 1, 0, COALESCE(CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('UserSocial'), 'UserSocial'[User Name] IN EXCEPT(INTERSECT(gp1Users, gp3Users), UNION(gp2Users, gp4Users)) ), 0) ),
      ( 1, 0, 1, 1, COALESCE(CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('UserSocial'), 'UserSocial'[User Name] IN EXCEPT(INTERSECT(INTERSECT(gp1Users, gp3Users), gp4Users), gp2Users) ), 0) ),
      ( 1, 0, 0, 1, COALESCE(CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('UserSocial'), 'UserSocial'[User Name] IN EXCEPT(INTERSECT(gp1Users, gp4Users), UNION(gp2Users, gp3Users)) ), 0) ),
      ( 1, 0, 1, 0, COALESCE(CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('UserSocial'), 'UserSocial'[User Name] IN EXCEPT(INTERSECT(gp1Users, gp3Users), UNION(gp2Users, gp4Users)) ), 0) ),
      ( 1, 1, 0, 1, COALESCE(CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('UserSocial'), 'UserSocial'[User Name] IN EXCEPT(INTERSECT(INTERSECT(gp1Users, gp2Users), gp4Users), gp3Users) ), 0) )
    },
    "Number of users", [Value5],
    "Instagram", [Value1],
    "Twitter", [Value2],
    "Facebook", [Value3],
    "YouTube", [Value4]
  )
```

Comment: I know zero about DAX but that just looks odd.  Do you really have to hardcode the Platforms to make that work?

Comment: Yes, when dealing with columns. Currently no pivot/unpivot functions in DAX.

Comment: @SamNseir Thanks a ton. :)

What you shared worked great. Only one problem is I am not trying to show the unique count of users. What I am trying to show is how many times they were active on each of these platforms. That means I need to replace DISTINCT function with something else?

Comment: PS: Each row means a time when a user tries to access a particular platform. So there are multiple entries for each user and platform combination.

Comment: yikes, urm, is a Venn Diagram the right thing for this? If I use Facebook once and Instagram 1,000 times, where would it place me in the venn diagram? Purpose is to show commonality/overlap and not the magnitude. How many unique users are you looking at?

Comment: If the answer to my above question (1 facebook, 1000 instagram) is to show 1001 in between those two, then yes, it can be done. Let me know.

Comment: These entries are basically ads that different users have seen on different platforms. I am trying to show how many ads were seen on different (and common platforms).

Comment: Yes @SamNseir You are correct. 1 fb + 1000 insta = 1001 times in the FB+ Insta common bucket on the Venn Diagram. 

I am not trying to categorize users but number of times they saw an ad. :)

Comment: Cool, I've updated the answer above with the two options. Use the second one.

Comment: @SamNseir Thanks a ton! This was exactly what I needed! :)